# Сортировка словаря по значениям через лямбда

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, dict

Приветсвую.
Дан словарь:

```
dic1 = {'е': '8.034067226347956', 'в': '4.499488003708411', 'о': '11.472326552944596', 
        'л': '5.152069547904425', 'с': '5.24838944394733', 'т': '5.725809362597864',
        'й': '1.1784463809746357', 'н': '6.453623014945732', 'а': '8.37907103544838', 
        'и': '6.716745413406134', 'р': '4.575670012215719', 'м': '2.9104946891071126', 
        'к': '3.4886040454356335', 'ч': '1.3536080065201161', 'п': '2.432504830243307', 
        'ь': '1.9923210055265201', 'я': '2.3112975448875415', 'ы': '1.942166266758617', 
        'б': '1.6112209829188917', 'у': '2.91315441010238', 'з': '1.8012010540094343', 
        'ш': '0.9533199967323427', 'ф': '0.21619732090103747', 'д': '3.0066246050789274', 
        'ж': '1.0211428821116664', 'ю': '0.6622705278216315', 'щ': '0.2866799272756288', 
        'г': '2.071732675242367', 'э': '0.2646422390291258', 'х': '0.8613696423245202', 
        'ц': '0.40997699341339094', 'ъ': '0.05376436011862355'}
```

Сортирую его так:

```
 sred1 = sorted(dic1.items(), key=lambda value: value[1])
```

На выходе получаю это:

> ```
> [('ъ', '0.05376436011862355'), ('ф', '0.21619732090103747'), ('э', '0.2646422390291258'), 
>  ('щ', '0.2866799272756288'), ('ц', '0.40997699341339094'), ('ю', '0.6622705278216315'), 
>  ('х', '0.8613696423245202'), ('ш', '0.9533199967323427'), ('ж', '1.0211428821116664'), 
>  ('й', '1.1784463809746357'), ('ч', '1.3536080065201161'), ('б', '1.6112209829188917'), 
>  ('з', '1.8012010540094343'), ('ы', '1.942166266758617'), ('ь', '1.9923210055265201'), 
>  ('о', '11.472326552944596'), ('г', '2.071732675242367'), ('я', '2.3112975448875415'), 
>  ('п', '2.432504830243307'), ('м', '2.9104946891071126'), ('у', '2.91315441010238'), 
>  ('д', '3.0066246050789274'), ('к', '3.4886040454356335'), ('в', '4.499488003708411'), 
>  ('р', '4.575670012215719'), ('л', '5.152069547904425'), ('с', '5.24838944394733'), 
>  ('т', '5.725809362597864'), ('н', '6.453623014945732'), ('и', '6.716745413406134'), 
>  ('е', '8.034067226347956'), ('а', '8.37907103544838')]
> ```

Вопрос:
Почему буква `о`, которая больше остальных, зависает в середине?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в значениях строки, а не вещественные числа, попробуйте сортировать так:

```
sred1 = sorted(dic1.items(), key=lambda value: float(value[1]))
```